# Unable to limit Memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a model using Tensorflow 2. I'm getting resource out of memory error. After going through various docs, I used the following code to fix it,

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')

# Currently, memory growth needs to be the same across GPUs
for gpu in gpus:
        tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)

tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(gpus[0], [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=512)])
```

Unfortunately, it still does not work. any other workaround?

Comment: You have the wrong approach, you cannot fix out of memory issues with some flags, it is a fundamental problem that means you might not have the required hardware or the model is just too big, so you could try a smaller model, but your question has no detail about the actual problem, only the solution you are trying (An XY problem).

Comment: I get this error even when I use colab though the batch size is 1 :(

Comment: Yeah sure, its a common problem, but if you do not provide any details, then there is nothing we can do to help you. There are no generic answers to these problems. Maybe the model is just too big for colab's GPU.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm trying to train yolo with input size of 416 and the batch size of 1 for  a total epoch of 10.

Comment: perhaps there is a conflict because you're configuring physical and virtual devices..."Memory growth cannot be configured on a PhysicalDevice with virtual devices configured."  --quote from TF docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth)